# Is it possible to show many2many_checkboxes values in multiple Lines in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Just i want to know is there any possibility to show the many2many_checkboxes in multiple lines?

For a field i have given like,

```
<field name="sports_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes" options="{'no_create_edit': True}" nolabel="1"/>
```

Now, how can i show all the check boxes in 3 lines?

Comment: I don't think we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating new widget for many2many field.

Create static folder with js, css, xml

Add new widget to odoo

```
instance.web.form.widgets.add('many2many_mycheckboxes',
                              'instance.web.form.MyCheckBoxes');
```

And then create widget

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Dachi Darchiashvili, i will try to implement your idea

Answer (score 0):

You can also give CSS style "column-count" for that particular field.